# Unable to transform Observable values using map

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to get a list from HttpClient in Angular but I'm having a problem with transforming the data from an Observable.

I have tried with static values also, but I'm getting the same result. When I try to transform values in an Observable using map() I get unmodified results back. See these two examples:

```js
import { from, map, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

// First example:
const observableOne$: Observable<number[]> = of([1, 2, 3]);
observableOne$.pipe(
  map((items: number[]) => {
    console.log('This will be ignored');
    return items.map((item: number): number => item + 100);
  }),
  map((items: number[]) => {
    console.log('This will also be ignored');
    items.push(4);
  })
);
observableOne$.subscribe((items: number[]) => console.log('First:', items));
// Output will be:
// First: [1, 2, 3]

// Second example:
const observableTwo$: Observable<number> = from([1, 2, 3]);
observableTwo$.pipe(map((item: number) => item + 100));
observableTwo$.subscribe((items: number) => console.log('Second:', items));
// Output will be:
// Second: 1
// Second: 2
// Second: 3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `pipe()` will not modifiy the original `Observable`. Instead it creates a **new** `Observable` which needs to be subscribed by someone. So when you are subscribing to `ObservableOne$`, you just get the original emitted values.

You have to `subscribe` to the `Observable` returned by the `pipe`.

```
const observableOne$: Observable<number[]> = of([1, 2, 3]);

observableOne$.pipe(
  map((items: number[]) => {
    console.log('This will be ignored');
    return items.map((item: number): number => item + 100);
  }),
  map((items: number[]) => {
    console.log('This will also be ignored');
    items.push(4);
    return items
  })
).subscribe((items: number[]) => console.log('First:', items));
```

Also notice that you missed the `return` statement in your second `map`. If you don't have a `return` statement inside a `map`, it will just return `undefined` which will be passed further down the chain.